# Excel exceeds maximum 65,536 rows in SSRS 2008R2 in XLS format error

Tags: excel-2007, ssis-2008

I get an error when i export data into Excel 2007 in the xls format.
The data seem to exceed 65000 row limit. i Didn't have this issue before.
I am using VS 2008 to create SSIS package in 2008 R2

Comment: Excel 2007 should be able to have up to 1M rows. Total number of rows and columns on a worksheet 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=2007

Comment: I don't want to change the format of xls to newer formats. like xlsx etc

Answer (score 0):

SSRS 2008 has a known issue with exceeding the 65000 row limit. You can resolve this by either upgrading your reporting server or you can split the result set into groups that can be split across multiple pages in the report.